# Избавление от OR в условии WHERE не через UNION для ускорения запроса SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть выборка по очень очень тяжелой таблице table1 со всеми индексами:

```sql
select 
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
 from table1
 -- (тут какие-то джойны)
 where col1='hello' or col2='world'
```

Могу ли избавиться от or в условии для ускорения не через union, а через мат логику:

```sql
(col1='hello' or col2='world') == not(col1<>'hello' and col2<>'world')
```

Будет ли такой вариант быстрее union?

Comment: *Могу ли избавиться от or в условии для ускорения не через union, а через мат логику* Визуально в тексте запроса - можете. Фактически в плане выполнения - сильно сомневаюсь. *Будет ли такой вариант быстрее union?* Быстрее UNION - возможно и будет. Быстрее UNION ALL - однозначно нет.

Comment: `not` и `<>` скорее всего это сразу мимо индексов, в отличие от строгого равенства. Возможно помогут индексы по этим двум колонкам и уже оптимизатор выберет какой использовать по ситуации (если оставить OR). UNION может быть тяжелее и медленнее в зависимости от кол-ва джойнов и других условий (т.к. запооса уже будет два сложных)